# How to make a CSS3 animation reusable?

Tags: css, animation

Without JQuery.

I have the following code but it will only work on one click. It will not be able to be used twice:

```
@-moz-keyframes lulse {
    0%{
        -moz-transform:scale(1);
    }
    20%{
        -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform:scale(1);
    }
}

.pinto {
    -moz-animation-name: lulse;
    -moz-animation-duration: .2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
}
```

Javascript:

```
onclick="changeClass(this.id);

function changeClass(a)
{
    document.getElementById(a).className += "pinto";

}
```

Comment: You might want to ask yourself, if you're already using Javascript, why not just implement the entire solution using Javascript? Many of the CSS3 won't be cross-browser compatible for years, you might find it easier to just deal with something like jQuery, which fixes that.

Comment: No thanks. I'll throw webkit and Opera code in there if I can figure it out.

Comment: I found this but it is JQuery: http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/ It says you need to remove and then readd the element to get it to work. I got the remove down to try it( function remove(b)
    {
gonzo=b;
     elemento = document.getElementById(gonzo);
     setTimeout("elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento);",800);}) Now maybe add a setTimeout at 900 ms to add it back but I can't figure that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, on the surface it looks like you should be able to remove the class at the beginning of your click handler if it exists.  Specifically:

```
function changeClass(a) {
    var elementA = document.getElementById(a);
    var regEx = new RegExp('(\\s|^)pinto(\\s|$)');
    elementA.className = elementA.className.replace(regEx,' ');
    elementA.className += " pinto";
}
```

This will remove the class and reapply it, which should restart the effect.

Comment: try to add the class name in a timeout 
    
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(a).className += "pinto";}, 1000);

Comment: Wow. Works with the setTimeout. Thanks.